# Comparing palindromes using different functions

Tags: c++, function, palindrome

I am trying to call the functions so that it prints out if the array is a palindrome or not. Please tell me what I am doing wrong; it seems I am not passing the arguments correctly. If I made a mistake with the post, please let me know; I  am fairly new to the website.

This is how the output is supposed to look:

[image]

This is what my output looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void createReverseArray();
void printArray();
void compareArray();

int main()
{
    int MyArray1[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1};
    int MyArray2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
    int MyArray3[] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1};
    int MyArray4[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1};

    int n = 5, i, j, n, temp;

    createReverseArray(MyArray1[5]);
    createReverseArray(MyArray2[5]);
    createReverseArray(MyArray3[5]);
    createReverseArray(MyArray4[5]);

    compareArray(MyArray1[5]);
    compareArray(MyArray2[5]);
    compareArray(MyArray3[5]);
    compareArray(MyArray4[5]);

    printArray(MyArray1[5]);
    printArray(MyArray2[5]);
    printArray(MyArray3[5]);
    printArray(MyArray4[5]);
}

int createReverseArray(int &a[], int n)
{
    i = 0;
    j = n - 1;

    while(i<j) {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return reverse = a[];
}

int compareArray(int &a[], int reverse)
{
    if(a[] == reverse) {
        printf("The array is a palindrome")
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}


void printArray(&a[])
{
    printf("Array elements are:%d", a[]);
    compareArray(a[]);
}
```

Comment: _"This is how the output is supposed to look like"_ And? What does it **really** look like? And why is that bad? You should include expected and actual output. _"Please tell me what I am doing wrong"_ is not a problem description; we have no idea why you think anything is wrong, as you didn't identify what the problem is.

Comment: Your compareArray function is not complete.

Comment: what is `reverse` in `createReverseArray()`?

Comment: `MyArray1[5]` --> `MyArray1` and so on.

Comment: @Adalcar well i wanted the reverse value of the array so i could compare it to the original

Comment: @Alex and where are you storing that reverse array?

If you intend to compare it to the original, you need to keep the original somewhere, but your comparison function tries to compare an integer to a pointer... I am shocked your program actually ran

Comment: In `createReverseArray()`, you `return reverse = a[]`, but how does that function know what `reverse` is? Is this really all of your code? Does it actually compile? And what do you expect to achieve by casting the result of that assignment to an `int`, and returning that from the function?

Comment: You should be able to modify `createReverseArray` so that is compares the values at indices `i` and `j` instead of copying. Job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure due to the amount of uncertainties I have with the provided code, but if your objective is simply to detect whether the array is a palindrome, it is exceedingly simple and can be done in a single function:

```
bool isPalindrome(int[] list, int size)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < size / 2 - 1; k++)
        if(list[k] != list[size - k - 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This will iterate half your array, comparing it to the second half and exiting the instant one value is  not equal to its mirror.

As for the mistakes in  your code, I might be able to point out some of the more obvious ones, for future reference:

1. Calling functions with incorrect number of arguments.
   Example: `createReverseArray(MyArray1[5])`.
2. Calling passing integers in place of arrays as arguments. Example:
   `MyArray[5]` is the integer in the sixth position of `MyArray`.
3. Ignoring scope and using variables without declaring them. Example: `i` and `j` from `main` being used in `createReverseArray`. THIS DOES NOT WORK.
4. Comparing an integer to an array pointer. Example: `if(a[] == reverse)`. No matter what you were trying to achieve, this will never give you a useful result.
5. Declaring different functions in your forward declaration and in your implementation. Example: `void createReverseArray();` and `int createReverseArray(int &a[], int n)`. You should declare them wit the same arguments and return values or the compiler will not understand they're the same thing.

Comment: that is actually really useful! i think i am going to go read up on arrays and functions a bit more and then try again thank you!

Comment: @Alex I added a few (slightly impolite but still maybe helpful) advices that may help you avoid some basic mistakes

Comment: Awesome thank  you! will note it down for future reference